# Inputs x1, x2, and x3 are all true then output y is true

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm in online school there's no guidance and I'm just completely unprepared for this. I am to write this as a logical statement using logic symbols for conjunction and implication.

Can someone help me understand what writing this as a logical statement would look like and proper writing style of the problem / answer.

Problem: Inputs x1, x2, and x3 are all true then output y is true.

I need help to know where to start and then maybe I can pick up some pace here. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: What happens for the other input values?

Comment: I don't know what notation you use. Something like $(x_1\land x_2\land x_3)\to y$ might be satisfactory. If your course is fussy about parentheses, one might need to modify to say $((x_1\land x_2)\land x_3)\to y$.  I imagine the problem said **If** $\dots$ then $\dots$.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas. Thats actually how the problem is given to me. But yes they did make clear about the use of parenthesis. This makes clear sense, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I misunderstood the question, I thought you were writing a logical function (as in Boolean logic).

Comment: @copper.hat I wasnt but I would surely like to know what that looks like. I have to learn (and pass) this in 10 weeks, I can use all the help I can get.